# Tags Vs Elements in HTML 5

Tags: html, tags

What are the differences between a tag and an element in HTML 5? Can someone give me a detailed explanation between both?

I'm asking this question because I see a lot of confusion on the web and even on the W3C website, where it is used interchangeably yet presented in a manner where it is different without further clarification.

So Far, from my understanding:

Tags:

In HTML there are two types of tags: paired tags and unpaired tags. A paired tag consists of text in-between a start tag and an end tag. An unpaired tag only contains a start tag.

Elements:

Have the same description as tags but with a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Element consists of both tag and content. The elements starts with a tag then content and then closing tag.

paragraph Tag:

```
<p>
```

paragraph Element:

```
<p>content</p>
```

For a universal definition check here:
https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#elements

Comment: Thank you Ali. So far I got this:

 An HTML element is an individual component of an HTML document that is defined by a starting tag. If the element contains content text, an ending tag is attached to delimit markup. Is my understanding correct? @AliSheikhpour

Comment: Yes. But there are some empty elements as well as `<br>`  and `<hr>` . Also I think a paired tag without content is also an Element where `<p>` is a starting tag and `</p>` is an end tag and `<p></p>` without any content is a paragraph element.

Comment: find the universal definition of element here: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#elements

Comment: Wow, that was helpful. Thanks again Ali. I tried to up-vote you but my reputation on this site is too low.

Comment: Thank you. you can accept the answer without up-voting.

Answer (score -1):

An HTML fime consists of elements. Each element has a tagname. Some examples of elements with paired tagnames are: 
   - div
   - p
   - head
   - body. 
Some examples of unpaired tagnames are: 
   - br
   - img 
   - link

In this example of an HTML file you can see a few elements with each its correct tagname:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>basic page</title>
  <head>

  <body>

    <h1>This is a title</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>

  </body>

</html>
```